# Perl: Look forward to command that has not run yet

Tags: perl

Suppose I have the following bit of code:

```
foreach my $site (@site) {
    my $enter = `curl -s "$site" -H "Referer: https://OTHERSITE.potato"`;
}
```

Would it be possible to print just the referer of the curl command (OTHERSITE.potato) *before* the `foreach` function?

I am unsure of how to begin because usually when I want to print something, it has already been stored as a string

Edit: Because some people are not understanding the question, assume `$enter` cannot be modified. Is there a way to "look forward" to retrieve the contents of `$enter` before the program even gets there?

Comment: You are right, your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: Why is your source code dynamic? Is something generating it?

Comment: So you're saying that you cannot change that line of code in your source file? But yet you somehow have enough control over the code that you could insert a line to read the variable. If you could post a less simplified version of this, I'm sure we could help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, store it as a string then, right?

```
my $referer = "OTHERSITE.potato";
print $referer,"\n";
foreach my $site (@site) {
  my $enter = `curl -s "$site" -H "Referer: https://$referer"`;
}
```

Comment: It has a dynamic value and changes based on the code (what I provided is a very simple example). Short of copying it every time, I would like it to be dynamic.

Comment: You have to be specific. What you write is not enough.