# Perl: Read system function as string

Tags: perl

Suppose I have:

```
my $enter = `curl -s "http://google.com"`;
```

Would it be possible to read `$enter` as a string as well? On top of running the curl function, I am trying to read it as a string so I can pull the website name (google.com)

Comment: What do you mean "read `$enter` as a string?"

Comment: I want to run the curl command and also store the URL as a string (in this case google.com)

Comment: I've poked through some of your other questions and cannot figure out what you're trying to do... but is there some reason you can't use the fact that it's right in front of you to "store" it somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl: Look forward to command that has not run yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357962/perl-look-forward-to-command-that-has-not-run-yet)

Comment: You can do this using the [`Backticks`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Backticks) module (beware: it uses source filtering, which is error-prone and [should generally be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785852/why-are-perl-source-filters-bad-and-when-is-it-ok-to-use-them)). However, there is probably a better way...could you please explain where the `curl` command comes from such that you think you're unable to access its contents directly? Perhaps you're reading it from a file or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the text inside the backticks is not made available in a variable. But there is nothing stopping you from putting it in a variable of your own and executing *that* string:

```
my $cmd = 'curl -s "http://google.com"';
my $enter = `$cmd`;
```

Comment: Or more realistically, `my $url = "http://google.com"; my $enter = \`curl -s $url\`;`

Comment: Oh sure, in the real world, but in the contrived example he seemed insistent on knowing the text of the command.

Comment: If one wants *realistic* one should use a module instead of backticks and `curl`.